# Delete ArrayList Entry from server side on pressing "Delete" Key in the JSP

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm currently using Spring MVC wherein I need to add and delete elements in my `<form:select>`:

```
<form:select path="listElements">
    <form:options items="${myList}" />
</form:select>
```

As of now, I'm populating elements in and deleting elements from the `ArrayList`, `myList`, from different pop-up pages and using AJAX to update the parent page.

I now want to change the deletion such that when I click on a populated option and press `Del`, it gets deleted (from the server side).

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1 You have to catch the Delete event using JS.

2 After catching the event get selected index value of the drop down or multi select window.

3 send this value / values to the server which will delete these fields in the Data base / what ever source you are using.

4 in response send an json which will send the fresh records for the drop down.

5 Populate these values into the drop down.

For drop down population and deleting the contents please refer some other tutorials.

Comment: I had more or less the same idea; I couldn't figure out how to do it though. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: First search for "Detect key events on web pages". Then Ajax calls than drop down creation with jS. work one by one you will surely get the solution.